# Какую схему именования модульных тестов лучше всего применять?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

У меня есть приложение, покрытое модульными тестами, которые запускаются так:

```
@manager.command
def test():
    '''Run the unit tests.'''
    import unittest
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests', pattern='*_test.py')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
```

После того как тесты пройдены у меня есть такой результат:

```
test_add_if_admin_exists (auth_add_user_test.UserAddidition) ... ok
test_add_wihout_admin_token (auth_add_user_test.UserAddidition) ... ok

// more lines

test_password_verify (usermodel_test.UserModel) ... ok
test_password_verify_if_invalid_password (usermodel_test.UserModel) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran <Кол-во тестов> tests in 0.445s

OK
```

Не устраивает меня следующее:

1. Слово 'test' и в названия модуля(py-файла) и метода. И там и там нужно!
2. И в названии класс и в названии модуля используются одни и те же слова. Для примера *auth_add_user_test* и *UserAddidition*

Как лучше всего именовать модули, тестовые классы и методы, чтобы из вывода можно было понять, что происходит без излишнего напрягания извилин?

Answer (score 2):

Начало нужных методов с префикса `test` - это общепринятая конвенция. [Судя по всему](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10100114/2908793), смена префикса будет не очень очевидной и может запутать тех, кто потом будет пользоваться этим кодом; в случае с питоном я бы просто с этим смирился (хотя,возможно, есть декораторы,выполняющие эту работу). В принципе, это просто четыре символа, not a big deal. Что до общих конвенций наименования - "по классике" рекомендуют называть тест фичей, которую он тестирует (`test_auth_system`), в яндексе распространена конвенция "название должно писать, что должно произойти" (shouldAuthorizeUserAgainstXxx, shouldMatchRegex, etc.)

> И в названии класс и в названии модуля используются одни и те же слова. Для примера auth_add_user_test и UserAddidition

Если честно, я опять не вижу здесь проблемы. Сейчас у вас там один методы, потом появится OAuth, а вместе с ним еще один тест. Это еще не самый большой геморрой по дублированию вещей.

Последнее, о чем хотел бы сказать - конечно же, [Allure](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python), хотя, кажется, там другой тестовый фреймворк. Allure позволяет задавать кастомные названия/описания для тестов, прикреплять файлы, объединять тесты в сценарии и оформлять это [читаемым отчетом](http://ci.qatools.ru/job/allure-core_master-deploy/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/allure-report-preview/target/allure-report/index.html#/).

Comment: Если дать такое  название "shouldAuthorizeUserAgainstXxx", то будет понятно только поведение,  но не состояние, которое приводит к такому состоянию. А мне хочется передавать идею более описательно, к примеру : "В модуле.... в случае добавления существующего пользователя должен возвращаться status_code 400". Пока в моих тестах передается только "состояние" if_invalid_password, но без поведения!

Comment: @sys_dev вы что тестируете, авторизацию или возвращаемые коды?

Comment: В модульном тестировании, как правило тестируются, не компоненты целиком, а их части по отдельности. Я тестирую некий  небольшой кусок production кода и после его работы хочу проверять все его артефакты и текст ошибки и статус код и если надо то сущестование добавленного пользователя и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: В модульном как раз обычно тестируются атомарные компоненты. Приложение целиком - это уже системный уровень. Но я вообще про то, что есть тестируется возвращение кода - пишите shouldReturn400OnInvalidAuth, авторизации - shouldFailAuthDueToBadRequest.

Comment: ОК. Содержание теста это тема другого вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется, то слово test из названия модуля можно убрать, надо только переместить все тесты в один пакет,  и подправить `TestLoader`. 
В одном модуле не обязательно содержится только один `TestCase`. 
Например в модуле `user_test.py` могут содержаться кейсы `AuthUserTestCase`, `AddUserTestCase`, `LoginUserTestCase`. Тогда название модуля и названия кейсов будут разными.

Comment: "Например в модуле user_test.py могут содержаться кейсы" - сильно не рекомендую

Comment: А можно более развернутый ответ пожалуйста - интересно узнать о разных подходах.